# Integration of Mongo and Quartz

Tags: mongodb, quartz

Mongo DB giving  below error when running the Quartz Jobs

```
2018-12-19 04:18:58 INFO  LockManager:tryLock:65 - Failed to lock trigger Camel_camel.SmartM2MInitialSync, reason: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: quartz.telit_locks index: keyGroup_1_keyName_1_type_1 dup key: { : "Camel_camel", : "SmartM2MInitialSync", : "t" }', details={ }}
2018-12-19 04:18:58 INFO  LockManager:relockExpired:89 - Trigger Camel_camel.SmartM2MInitialSync hasn't expired yet. Lock time: Sat Dec 15 02:59:49 UTC 2018
```

**Reason**
As the Quarz Lock table already had the entry, but somehow entry was not deleted as MongoDB got disconnected when Quarz jar tried removing the entry.

Comment: Added the Time To Live index on the lock table field (default table created by Quartz jar)

Comment: db.getCollection('quartz_locks').createIndex( { "time": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )

Answer (score 0):

Added the Time To Live index on the lock table field (default table created by Quartz jar)

db.getCollection('telit_locks').createIndex( { "time": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )

it removed the expired entries from the quartz lock table of schedule job. Now its working fine